# Copy-Item does not displays verbose messages even when $VerbosePreference is 'Continue'

Tags: powershell

If I run `Copy-Item "C:\Temp\A.txt" "C:\Temp\B.txt" -Verbose`, I get the following output message:

> VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Copy File" on target "Item:
>   C:\Temp\A.txt Destination: C:\Temp\B.txt".

But when I run

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

Copy-Item "C:\Temp\A.txt" "C:\Temp\B.txt"
```

nothing is displayed. Is this correct? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: A good workaround for this is to use [$PSDefaultParameterValues](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/how-to-use-psdefaultparametervalues/) such as `$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Copy-Item:Verbose', $True)` if you're only interested in a few functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$VerbosePreference` variable relates to the `Write-Verbose` command. It does not automatically add the `-Verbose` switch to other commands.

To get the functionality I believe you're after, I normally do this:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

if($VerbosePreference -eq "Continue"){
    Copy-Item "C:\Temp\A.txt" "C:\Temp\B.txt" -Verbose
}else{
    Copy-Item "C:\Temp\A.txt" "C:\Temp\B.txt"
}
```